# Laravel 7 undefined method

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm creating a custom controller for Login but attempt is showing as undefined, I'm unable to resolve, please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SM7c.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the **exact** error message

Comment: Please share the code using the ```code markup``` and not an image

Answer (score 1):

changes your varaibles like this :

```
$user = $request->input('username');
$pass = $request->input('password');
```

If it's still not working, try to do it like this:

At the top of your file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Then :

```
$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return view('template.index');
        }
```

This should work
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Answer (score 1):

To use the Auth Facade you have to include the auth Facades.

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`